# How can I make a photo which fit the div shape using css

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm working on a web application, and part of my work is to realize interfaces using `HTML` and `CSS`.

I want to add a div that will contain the user profile photo, but my div is a circle and all my photos have different rectangular shapes. I want to know how I can make a photo that can fit the circular size of my div using `CSS` and maybe `JavaScript`.

At this moment I'm using this code :

HTML

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

 #photo
 img(src="img/profil-cercle.png")

<!-- end snippet -->
```

CSS

```css
#photo
  img
    width 100%
    height 100%
```

It works only for photos that already have a circular format.

Comment: Show us your code..Provided code is not enough to evaluate the problem..

Comment: If your `DIV` is already circular then you can give one css to div `overflow:hidden`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is required to be inline (i.e. not  a background-image) then I assume you would want it centered.

There are various techniques for doing that but flexbox works well.

Firstly, the div needs to be square (you haven't mentioned the size so I picked an arbitrary number).

Then we round it with `border-radius:50%` and stop any *excess* image from showing by adding `overflow:hidden`.

Then center:

```css
#profile {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* required */
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* required */
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="profile">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="">
</div>
```

Note the image is **larger** than the square *but* it is rectangular....the image itself does not need to be square.

Whether centering gives you the actual look you want is a separate issue.

The image can be "scaled" to the maximum height of the div with:

```
img {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo (scaled)**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lw4zft28/)

Comment: Thank you @Paulie_D very much ! That was exactly what I was looking for without deform the photo and display it correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the background-image in a circular div

```css
#profile {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/200/200/");
}
```

```html
<div id="profile">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set a border-radius at 50% to the img you can achieve that circle image.

HTML

```
<div id="photo">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#photo img {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: This assumes the image is a square...which is not the case.

Comment: In that case you can assign a fixed width and height to the #photo div and give position absolute to the image. So it would look like this: http://codepen.io/miguelmorera/pen/BKrZwL

Answer (score -1):

CSS:

```
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: This assumes the image is a square...which is not the case.